# Windows can't connect to the Samba Linux AD Tests also returns problems with Admin and Krb5

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, samba4

I am trying to create a Linux Domain Controller on my virtualbox using Samba although it's working but can't reach servers?

Detail Information: 
**Software:** VirtualBox
**Distro for Server:** Debian9
**Windows Desktop:** Windows 10 or Windows 7
**Network Type:** Internal (For both Server and Desktop)
Packages: Samba, Samba-Client, KRB5

I have done the following pings

```
$ ping dc1.tjh.com
$ ping 192.168.100.1
$ ping dc1
```

Those were pinging successfully.

```
$ ping tjh.com
```

This ping responded:

```
ping: tjh.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Obviously this was because my network is set to internal as the same responded for 'google.com' so I ruled this issue out of the problem.

**Here are my commands and checks for the Samba and krb5:**

```
$ smbclient -L localhost -U%
```

Responded:

```
Domain=[TJH] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    netlogon        Disk      
    sysvol          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.5.12-Debian)
Domain=[TJH] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]
    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    DC1                  Samba 4.5.12-Debian
    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    TJH                  DC1
```

I assume there are no problems there. So I ran the following code for Samba:

```
$ smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator
$ Enter Administrator's password:
```

Responded:

```
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS
```

I also tried testing the Krb5 below:

```
$ kinit administrator
```

Responded:

```
Kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "TJH.COM" while getting initial credentials
```

Tested the DNs using the `host` command:

```
$ host -t A dc1.tjh.com
```

Responded:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Can anyone help me out please? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In the lower output of `service samba-ad-dc status`, does it give any error or warning about the DNS service? To fix this i had to remove the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and replace it with a static file with this content:

```
domain example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

restart `systemd-resolved` and `samba-ad-dc` services and check the service status again. If the dns warning is gone, you should be able to ping your AD domain and use `kinit`.

This tutorial has all you need:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-active-directory-ubuntu/

For Ubuntu 18.04, check out the differences on this one:
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=samba&f=4
Also the edits in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file should be placed in the yaml file in `/etc/netplan/`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your question what you've done...  Have you installed Samba on your Linux server and provisioned it as a domain controller?

When working with Samba, you should always use the "official" documentation, e.g.:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

And you need to make sure dns resolution is working properly, otherwise you won't be able to join PCs to your domain.